# Can Kinect Capture Eye Gestures?

Tags: xbox360

I want to know that if Microsoft Kinect can capture the eye gestures? I would like to use it for a project.

Comment: How far away will the "subject" be from the camera?

Comment: one meter or less maybe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems unlikely, but I don't know from experience. I would expect that the resolution necessary to track eye movements would be greater than the resolution necessary to track [hand rotation](http://www.dailytech.com/Microsoft+Working+to+Quadruple+Kinect+Resolution/article20436.htm). It might be possible with [heavy processing of the two images](http://forums.dpreview.com/forums/readflat.asp?forum=1022&message=18379174&changemode=1), but this will probably reduce the ability to do tracking in real-time. The kinect camera's resolutions are relatively low ([640x480 at 30Hz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinect))

Comment: i think that would be easier to use a webcam for this purpose right?

Comment: I think you are looking for something pretty high resolution at a high frame rate. There are a few webcams that are probably up to the task.